# Error on Java web socket implementation

Tags: java, websocket, grizzly, tyrus

I'm connecting to a web socket server via my Java application using Grizzly web socket implementation.

```
@OnError
public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
    Log4Me.getLogger().debug("WebSocket Error {} on session {} ", session, t);
    Log4Me.getLogger().error("Error on session {}, Exception:{}", session.getId(), t.getMessage());

}

@OnClose
public void closedConnection(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
    Log4Me.getLogger().info("Session closed. session: {}, Reason {}", session, reason);
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, ByteBuffer message) {
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
}
```

Most of the time it works as expected but sometimes the onError callback is caled. When I run the application after removing the @OnError annotation, I get an exception:

```
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.callMethod(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:477)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.access$100(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:87)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint$WholeHandler$1.onMessage(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:573)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusSession.notifyMessageHandlers(TyrusSession.java:562)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onMessage(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:758)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onMessage(TyrusWebSocket.java:187)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.BinaryFrame.respond(BinaryFrame.java:93)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.process(ProtocolHandler.java:635)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusClientEngine.java:664)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter$ProcessTask.execute(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:472)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.TaskProcessor.processTask(TaskProcessor.java:114)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.TaskProcessor.processTask(TaskProcessor.java:91)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:270)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems that it is trying to call a method of my class but it fails.. But I don't know any idea why it fails to the error case...
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The stacktrace seems to happen because you removed the annotation which marks the method to handle the error. It's not the reason for the error. You might want to concentrate your research on the error itself. A first step would be to **tell us what error message you get from the error handler**.

Comment: + please include info about used versions; Tyrus will be more relevant than Grizzly (and if you can, include your packaging - which bundle do you use or maven depepndencies, …)